# Parsing a value through href to be used by server in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to parse a value of a product `(i.e hamburger whose product-id is 1002)` so that it can be received and displayed by the server.

```
<area class="hamburger" shape="rect" coords="0,60,110,110" href="cartAction.php?1002">
```

It is being referred to on `PHP` side by

```
foreach ($_GET as $k => $v) {
    $product = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_id, product_name, unit_price, unit_quantity FROM products WHERE product_id = '$k'");
    while ($obj = $product->fetch_object()) {
        $product_id = $obj->product_id;
        if ($k == $obj->product_id) {
            $_SESSION['currentProduct'] = $product_id;
        }
    }
}
//redirect back to original page
header('Location:'.$return_url);
```

After clicking on the area/image I am presented with a 404 error not found which when looked at, displays an incomprehensible url

> The requested URL /POTI/WebContent/aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9QT1RJL1dlYkNvbnRlbnQvPzEwMDE9Vmlldw== was not found on this server."

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9QT1RJL1dlYkNvbnRlbnQvPzEwMDE9Vmlldw==`is Base64, when you decode that you get `http://localhost/POTI/WebContent/?1001=View`

Comment: @huggilou would you be able to shed light as to why my redirect might not be working ? `$return_url` is initialised with `$return_url = $_SESSION['current_url']`

Comment: Where do you set your `$return_url` var ?

Comment: The following code, which is placed above the posted code. `$return_url = $_SESSION['current_url']; //return url`

Comment: The session variable is initialised in a separate .php page with the following code
`$_SESSION['current_url'] = base64_encode("http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");`

Comment: Why didn't you decode the base 64 in your header call ? `header('Location:'.base64_decode($return_url));`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass variable name in following way.

```
<area class="hamburger" shape="rect" coords="0,60,110,110" href="cartAction.php?productid=1002">
```

You can get the value on server side as:

```
$value = $_GET['productid'];
```